# Сохранение цвета текста при обработке .rtf документа с RichTextBox.Rtf (c#)

Tags: c#, rtf, xlsx

Добрый день!
Программа обрабатывает .rtf файл, выбирает из него некоторые строки и записывает в файл другого формата (xlsx).
Я принимаю на вход .rtf и работаю с ним через RichTextBox.Rtf:

```
 string rtfText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
 rtBox.Rtf = rtfText;
 string plainText = rtBox.Text;
```

Проблема в том, что plainText в результате является обычным текстом. Но некоторые подстроки исходного .rtf имеют другой цвет, мне нужно этот цвет сохранить. Можно ли как-нибудь сохранить коды цветов (не считая параллельного прохождения по rtf вместе с plainText), работая с RTB, или это не мой вариант? Получается, мне нужна либо конвертация в xlsx, а не Text, либо некая частичная конвертация?...
Спасибо :)

P.S. Текст использует юникодные символы (например, русские буквы), поэтому в вопросе простой конвертации rtBox очень удобно использовать. Слова, используемые в цветных подстроках, нельзя однозначно привязать к цвету (в одной строке конкретное слово может быть выделено цветом, в другой - нет).

Comment: Можно разобрать текст на отдельные слова, каждое слово записать в словарь, и сопоставить ему исходный цвет. Можно сохранять координаты Можно использовать какую-то разметку, и разбирать текст перед вставкой в таблицу. Варианты могут быть разные - зависит от того, что вы делаете дальше. А вот при помощи `string plainText = rtBox.Text;` цвет вы точно не передадите - это чистый текст, и ничего кроме.

Comment: Да, если бы я не понимала, что plainText - это чистый текст, то и вопроса этого не родилось бы) Словарь с координатами не подходит, потому что текст не английский. То есть координаты этих подстрок в тексте и координаты этих подстрок в rtf совершенно разные, и до конвертации верные цифры не вычленить, ибо код (а после конвертации не вычленить ибо нечего уже вычленять). Собственно, этим вопросом я пытаюсь выяснить, есть ли какой-нибудь ещё подходящий функционал у rtBox. Вдруг. Хотя сама пока ничего не могу найти(

Comment: Я подправил исходный комментарий, теперь там вариант получше (на мой взгляд)

Comment: eastwing, спасибо за правки, я, в свою очередь, подправила пост)

Comment: 1. rtf - формат не тяжёлый. Скачайте спецификацию, почитайте "теги", таблицу цветов, и кодировку. В один цикл вы скорее всего сможете перекодировать. Приведу вам теги жирный /b /b0, переход /pard  символы /'aa. Вариант 2 - считать компонентом атрибуты текста.

Comment: nick_n_a, мне кажется, это не очень круто - ручками раскодировать rtf при наличии там тех же русских букв. Я, кажется, нашла другое решение, сейчас проверяю) Но про спецификацию - спасибо, она мне пригодится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант решения, который использовала я:
перед конвертацией пройтись по rtf коду и в начале и конце окрашенных частей вставить спецсимволы, означающие окраску, которые rtBox не тронет (например, BLUEBEGIN). А после конвертации пройтись и заменить это на окраску.

Comment: Костыли... Что мешает сразу сделать то, что требуется?

Comment: Что значит "сделать сразу то, что требуется"?

Comment: Ну например, составить массив пар строка+цвет.

Comment: Одна и та же подстрока может быть окрашена любым из возможных цветов, или не окрашена совсем. И в какой момент составлять? Либо я записываю в качестве строки rtf-ный код (который придётся повторно отдельно расшифровывать, это тоже так себе решение), либо я сначала перевожу текст (и теряю цвета вообще).